# VLookup cannot find match

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I try to perform VlookUp using VBA. Specifically **I want to find Open prices for each Date** **(picture attached)**. But my code fails to find any matches. I Guess i have messed up ranges for vlookup but I cannot find the mistake.

```
Sub VlookUp()

Dim goalsWs As Worksheet, dataWs As Worksheet
Dim goalsLastRow As Long, dataLastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim dataRng As Range

Set goalsWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("[FULL_TABLE][1]")
Set dataWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BTC-USD")

goalsLastRow = goalsWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
dataLastRow = dataWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set dataRng = dataWs.Range("A2:G" & dataLastRow)
For x = 2 To goalsLastRow
    On Error Resume Next
    goalsWs.Range("B" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VlookUp( _
    goalsWs.Range("A" & x).Value, dataRng, 4, False)

Next x


End Sub
```

I want to find Open prices from BTC-USD for each Date in FULL_TABLE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the data type " the Excel worksheet function gets confused with the array of VBA dates which are always US-centric.

As suggested convert the dates to intrinsic values which you can do simply with the Value2 property, eg x = Range("Source").Value2"

So simply adding (2) after (value) has fixed the problem
`goalsWs.Range("A" & x).Value2, dataRng, 4, False)`